# Pretty format JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I want to put `<span>` around some numbers in pretty-printed JSON output.

I am using `JSON.stringify()` with a *replacer* to do this.  However, as the returned type of an HTML fragment with a span in is a string, these now get quoted.

How can I put spans around numbers?

An example:

```
JSON.stringify(
    {
        with_span:1,
        without_span:1
    },
    function(key,value) {
        if(key=="with_span")
            return '<span>'+value+'</span>'; // but I don't want this quoted! :(
        return value;
    },
    4) // the indent
```

outputs:

```
{
    "with_span": "1",
    "without_span": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with `JSON.stringify()`.

`JSON.stringify()` will return a valid JSON string, and Without the quotes it is not a valid json string.

To achieve what you want, you have to traverse the object yourself and render it as HTML.

I don't know your use case, but maybe you could just use a library to do the work? For example  [google-code-prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Answer (score 1):

Take the stringify() function from [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) (public domain - not copyrighted) and modify it to output formatted HTML.